# Is there a ruby gem to start/stop Windows Scheduled Tasks?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking for a ruby gem that can start/stop an already running windows scheduled tasks. Or if a gem does not exist, another work around for doing such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the best answer, but someone else can please correct me if I'm wrong. I think my best option is to just send a command using the Windows CLI.

Looking at the windows [the windows documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748925.aspx) it appears the command to stop a task in Windows CLI is `schtasks /End [/S <system> [/U <username> [/P [<password>]]]] /TN taskname`.

The command to start a task is `schtasks /Run [/S <system> [/U <username> [/P [<password>]]]] /TN <taskname>`.

So, with those two things in mind, in the ruby script I can use `%x(windows cli command)`, `system 'windows cli command'`, with varying levels of returned data. I believe there's some more from what I was reading, but I think that will work. Again, if anyone has comments or a better plan on action for what I'm trying to do, definitely all ears.